# IDE/GUI for Autohotkey script creation

Tags: windows, autohotkey, user-interface

I have many non-technical minded friends who could benefit greatly from the customisability of AHK but who are scared of the concept of scripting. Just wondering if there already exists some user interface to create scripts instead of using Notepad, and somewhat similar to Apple's Automater?

I'm on Windows 7.

[image: automater image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Old thread but maybe someone can benefit if they stumble on it.

There is an application [here](http://ahkscript.org/boards/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=143) called Macro Creator Create Scripts & Macros Faster and Easily! It is written by **Pulover**

Here is description:

> Pulover's Macro Creator is a Free Automation Tool and Script
>   Generator. It is based on AutoHotkey language and provides users with
>   multiple automation functions, as well as a built-in recorder. Macros
>   can be executed from the program itself or you can export them to
>   AutoHotkey Script format or a standalone executable.

Can be downloaded [here](http://www.macrocreator.com/download) or from [Softpedia](http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/System-Miscellaneous/Pulover-s-Macro-Creator.shtml) or [Github](https://github.com/Pulover/PuloversMacroCreator) but I can't place links apparently due to having less than 10 reputation points!!!

edit:

added the links :)

Comment: Brilliant example of why there's nothing wrong with posting a valid answer to an old question. Thanks @MerlinW, that's a great link and closest to the answer I was after :)

Comment: Thank you @jay and glad that was helpful. Updating the links now :)

Answer (score 1):

In short, no. No block-style script builder exists for AutoHotKey. But there is a macro generator (Check C:\Program Files\AutoHotKey\Extras) and a [GUI Builder](http://www.autohotkey.com/download/smartgui.zip)[ZIP]. You can get pretty close to an IDE though with this modded [SciTE build](http://www.autohotkey.net/~fincs/SciTE4AutoHotkey_2/web/).

Answer (score 1):

There are instructions for getting syntax highlighting for AutoHotkey set up in Notepad++ [here](http://www.autohotkey.com/forum/topic19404.html).

Answer (score 0):

Adam Pash over at [lifehacker](http://lifehacker.com) has written a small app called [Texter](http://lifehacker.com/238306/lifehacker-code-texter-windows):

> Unlike software-specific text
>   replacement features, Texter runs in
>   the Windows system tray and works in
>   any application you're typing in.
>   Texter can also set return-to markers
>   for your cursor and insert clipboard
>   contents into your replacement text,
>   in addition to more advanced keyboard
>   macros. Did we mention it's free?

It is built for easy, stand alone creation of AutoHotKey's [Hotstring text replacement](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotstrings.htm) functions. You can make it do more than text, as it can send any keys that AutoHotKey recognizes (like `{Tab}`). (See under the heading `Advanced Use`).

Also, it is written in AutoHotKey itself:

> Finally, Texter is open source,
>   written using AutoHotkey, so if you're
>   an AutoHotkey user and you want to
>   check out or run Texter from the
>   source, grab the source code.

So you could grab the source and tweak it to add the options for the things your friends want it to do.